# Is there something similar to Source Code Outliner Power Toy for VS2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ide

I absolutely love the Source Code Ouliner power toy that I use in VS2005 but am upgrading to 2010 and it seems they haven't yet released a new version. Is there anything similar that shows you a basic outline of the file you are currently navigating?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), amongst many other features, has a [File Structure window](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#File_Structure) which does the same as Source Outliner.

Comment: I broke down and bought resharper. File structure is pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

For a free one, try the Solution Navigator in the [Microsoft Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef).

Comment: Saw that but I'm really looking for something that justs displays the current file's contents.

Answer (score 1):

Like you, I found this a totally great plug in that saved on the order of minutes per day.  No more searching for functions!  Luckily Source Outliner has been re-created for VS2010 and is still free.  However, sbohlen updated it and it now runs on the (free) DXCore environment.  I have been using it ever since I upgraded to VS2010.

You can read along as I got this set up, downloaded all the parts and got it running.

http://unhandled-exceptions.com/blog/index.php/2010/05/23/plugins-for-dxcorecoderushxpresscoderushrefactor-pro-201014-rtm-available/

The download is here:

http://code.google.com/p/dxsourceoutliner/downloads/list

You will also need the DXCore community installer from http://www.devexpress.com

But as a ReSharper user for years now, I will use the File Structure - same sort of view and already built in to R#.